# can't find the error in Depth First Search code that runs forever

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search

Trying to implement Depth First Search. Implemented adjacency list using vector. Keeping track of vertices that have been explored by set "explored". "s" is the starting vertex. I think the problem is in while loop but can't figure out.

```
void AddEdge(vector<vector<int>>& adjList, int u, int v) {
    adjList[u].push_back(v);
    adjList[v].push_back(u);
}

    void dfs(vector<vector<int>>& adjList, int s) {
    stack<int> adjacent;
    set<int> explored;
    adjacent.push(s);
    while(adjacent.size() != 0) {
        int vertex = adjacent.top();
        adjacent.pop();
        if(explored.count(vertex) == 0)
            explored.insert(vertex);
            for(vector<int>::iterator itr = adjList[vertex].begin(); 
                    itr != adjList[vertex].end(); ++itr) {
                adjacent.push(*itr);
            }
    }
    for(set<int>::iterator itr = explored.begin(); itr != explored.end(); 
        ++itr) {
        cout << "vertices reachable from " << s << " are " << "--> " << * 
        (itr);
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this can help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: You're pushing elements that already have been visited. I don't think this will cause an endless loop (as they should get ignored when re-visiting), but at least slow down your algorithm. Better: `while() { pop(); explored.insert(); for() { if(!explored) { push(); } } }`

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is misleading you: the `for` loop is not inside the `if` block, and so it will make that `adjacent` gets the neighbors of visited vertices too. That ensures that the outer loop never ends.

Fix by adding braces:

```
    if(explored.count(vertex) == 0) { // <-- brace
        explored.insert(vertex);
        for(vector<int>::iterator itr = adjList[vertex].begin(); 
                itr != adjList[vertex].end(); ++itr) {
            adjacent.push(*itr);
        }
    } // <-- brace
```